# Bibliography in chapter*

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, chapters

How can I customize the bibliography commands, so that the bibliography header would be `\chapter*{Bibliography}`?  The document class is `report`, and I am using BibTeX with a plain style.  The current commands are

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

I prefer not to use a method that will force me to inline the entire bibliography environment inside the document - It is rather lengthy.

Comment: Isn't that the default?  A test file with the `report` class using `natbib` (and running plain `bibtex`) resulted in the bibliography being written in the same size and style of a chapter heading, but without the bibliography showing up in the table of contents.  You might need to explain what you're after a little more clearly, ideally with a full-but-minimal example.

Comment: If you show the difficulties by a [concrete example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), it will be much easier to recognize the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some snippets from [report.cls](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls).

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
```

...

```
\newcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
```

So, `\chapter*{Bibliography}` is the default, and you can change the heading by redefining `\bibname`, e.g. `\renewcommand\bibname{References}`. If you want to make more substantial changes, you could use the [etoolbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{\section*{\bibname}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{a}
A nice book.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the KOMA classes, there is a nice little option you can use to move your bibliography *down* one step in the chapter/section hierarchy:

```
\KOMAoption{bibliography}{leveldown}
```

If the class typesets the bibliography as a `\chapter*` in standard usage, adding this KOMA option will make it a `\section*`.