# How to write "References" title after each thesis chapter instead of "Bibliography"

Tags: bibliographies, naming

I need to write "References" title at the end of each chapter instead of "Bibliography". My codes are simply

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
....
\end{thebibliography}
```

I tried with adding

```
\addtocaptionsenglish{References}
```

and

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{References}
```

but they didn't work.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: this has probably been answered before ... to change this title, you need to `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}`, or possibly `\renewcommand{\refname}{References}`.  what this string is known as depends on the document class.

Comment: \renewcommand{\bibname}{References} worked for me. I am sorry if it has been asked before. Thanks again.

Comment: these questions cover the same territory, but the answers are not all crystal clear: [Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12597/579); [Code to title the bibliography 'References' instead of Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32885/579); [Bibliography in chapter*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46517/579) and [Change Bibliography name to “References” and add it to TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108941/579) (among others)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!